# Added span disappears What should I do?(HTML + jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to input emoji into my div as spantag.
But then the span tag disappears.

I think we're deleting the added span tag at the end of the event.
Is there a good way?

And if the string in the cursor is span when there is still span in break mode.
It's registered as a sub-span of an already existing span.
Is there a good way to do this?

```js
$('#create_AAcontentsDIV').bind('keydown paste input', function() {
  const splitter = new GraphemeSplitter();
  var text;

  switch (event.type) {
    // case "keydown":
    //   event.preventDefault();
    // break;
    case "paste":
      if (!checkEmojis(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
      text = event.clipboardData.getData("text");
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.id = "emojispan";
      span.innerHTML = text;
      insertNodeAtCursor(span);
      break;
    case "input":
      if (!checkEmojis(event.data)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
      if (nullCheck(event.data)) return;
      text = event.data;
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.id = "emojispan";
      span.innerHTML = text;
      insertNodeAtCursor(span);
      break;
    default:
  }

});



function insertNodeAtCursor(node) {
  var range, html;
  if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.insertNode(node);
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    html = (node.nodeType == 3) ? node.data : node.outerHTML;
    range.pasteHTML(html);
  }
}



function checkEmojis(str) {
  const regex = /(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g;
  var regg = new RegExp(regex);
  return regg.test(str);
}
```

```css
#create_AAcontentsDIV {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/grapheme-splitter@1.0.4/index.min.js"></script>


<div id="create_AAcontentsDIV" class="aaEditor-textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: I closed your div and made it more visible. Also `.bind` is deprecated for `.on`

Comment: I added GraphemeSplitter but where is checkEmoji?

Comment: CheckEmoji() is simply a function of checking if it is an emoji.
I added it to the text just in case.

Comment: .bind is old?
I'll see if the .on is the same.

Comment: How to recreate the issue? It looks like it works

Comment: Sorry. Actually, it's my first time asking a question in Stack Overflow, so I'm not familiar with UI.
I don't know what I did.

Comment: Ok, so how do I recreate the issue? I had to close your div to make a [mcve]

Comment: I don't understand why your example is adding a span tag without any problems.
Can I check the difference a little bit more?
Or would it be helpful for me to upload my source?

Comment: It is your source. I only added a missing `</div>` and the jquery library

Comment: I've been looking for something different.
I have no idea.

Comment: Thank you!!
event.returnValue = false;
I put this phrase in and solved it.
Thank you.